# jQuery simple color picker, pallette won't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

Recently I started using jQuery Simple Color picker ([GITHUB](https://github.com/recurser/jquery-simple-color)) and encountered an annoying problem, with two or more color pickers on page, pallete won't disappear when I open second one (as you can see below). I am out of ideas about solution, because there is no `onOpen` or similar event, I cant even add `onClick` listener (don't know why, but my guess is, that its overridden somewhere in library). Is there anything I can do, I would really appreciate your advice, because I would hate to switch libraries.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

EDIT: Code like this is not working for me, tried same for clickable div, its cotainer and pallette div. Code is working on simple button.

```
  $('.simple_color').click(function(event) {
      $('.simple_color_custom_cell_size').closeChooser();
  });
```

[image]

Comment: a picture may be worth a thousand words, but it's worth zero lines of code ... add your (minimal) code to the question, perhaps you're doing it wrong

Comment: I see a button and a click function for close, $('input').closeChooser() and onClose: function(element) on this example page . Page: https://github.com/recurser/jquery-simple-color/blob/master/examples/index.html

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, but my goal is to close all pallettes (so there is always only one open), when user clicks to input (or in another words, he opens new pallette). Ofcourse those palletes close when user click somewhere outside of input, or i can even add button which will close them, but users wont click outside or on some button when they filling a form. And adding onClick event to input or clickable div which replace input is not working for me.